# TypeScript error notification in VS2012 Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

Is it possible to have Web Essentials display errors for all .ts files in the project rather than just the ones that are open?  [or] is it possible to see the output of failed ts compilations when doing a rebuild on .ts files in the project?

As it stands I am somewhat blind to errors unless I open all the files.  Even rebuilding all .ts files seems to mask the errors.

Comment: If you're getting WE to actually rebuild all the TS files when you ask it to do so, you're a good step ahead of me :-). In my experience, the TS add-in+WE will show you errors in files you have open + files that depend on them + files that they depend on. It's precisely for this reason that I asked Mads to add the "Build All" feature, but it doesn't seem to work yet. See http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3534369-menu-option-to-build-all-typescript-files.

Comment: @KenSmith Agreed. If a file isn't either open, or directly referenced by a file you have open, it does not get built, even with compile-on-build switched on.

Comment: this problem becomes more painful when dealing with lots of ts files. You can't figure out if any file has failed to be compiled until something weired happens in the web application!

Answer (score 0):

Web Essentials only shows errors in the preview pane, so you'll only see an error in the current file, or if the current file has an error caused by a file it depends on.

When you build your solution, you should get errors in the `Error List` view if there are any compilation problems.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that there are no errors in the Error List when we build or compile all ts files (when there are definitely errors).  If the answer is simply no, I'll take it.  If you're seeing a different behavior I would be interested in hearing how you have your project/environment set up.

Comment: You may need to "switch on" compile on build in your project file if it isn't already on. You can check by looking at the source of your project file and looking for the PostBuildEvent that calls `tsc`.